# Extract doctype with simple_html_dom

Tags: php, doctype, simple-html-dom

I am using [`simple_html_dom`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse a website.
Is there a way to extract the doctype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents` function to get all HTML data from website.
For example

```
<?php
   $html = file_get_contents("http://google.com");
   $html = str_replace("\n","",$html);
   $get_doctype = preg_match_all("/(<!DOCTYPE.+\">)<html/i",$html,$matches);
   $doctype = $matches[1][0];
?>
```

Comment: unfortunately I need to implement it using simple_html_dom.php

Comment: Have you tried to look for doctype by this code? $html->find('!DOCTYPE')

Comment: yeah. I have tried $html->find('!DOCTYPE'), $html->find('DOCTYPE'), $html->find('doctype'), $html->find('!doctype').
None of them worked for me.

Comment: It's strange because simple_html_dom.php has a pice of code below // doctype, cdata & comments... if (isset($tag[0]) && $tag[0]==='!') { $node->_[HDOM_INFO_TEXT] = '<' . $tag . $this->copy_until_char('>'); so this construction should work. Maybe you use old version of simple_html_dom.php file?

Comment: Here is my code:
        $resultArray = $this->htmlDom->find('!DOCTYPE');
        //var_dump($resultArray);
        
        if (is_array($resultArray) && count($resultArray) > 0)
        {
           $this->docType = $resultArray[0]->content;
           
        }

Comment: What this code prints?  $resultArray = $this->htmlDom->find('!'); print_r($resultArray);

Comment: It prints an empty array:
Array
(
)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$html->find('unknown')`. This works - at least - in version 1.11 of the simplehtmldom library. I use it as follows:

```
function get_doctype($doc)
{
    $els = $doc->find('unknown');

    foreach ($els as $e => $el) 
        if ($el->parent()->tag == 'root') 
            return $el;

    return NULL;
}
```

That's just to handle any other 'unknown' elements which might be found; I'm assuming the first will be the doctype. You can explicitly inspect `->innertext` if you want to ensure it starts with `'!DOCTYPE '`, though.