# How to skip links containing file extensions while web scraping using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, web-scraping, web-crawler

Here is a function that validates .edu TLD and checks that the url does not point to a .pdf document or a .doc document.

```
public function validateEduDomain($url) {
    if( preg_match('/^https?:\/\/[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.edu/i', $url) && !preg_match('/\.(pdf)|(doc)$/i', $url) )  {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
```

Now I am encountering links that point to jpg, rtf and others that simple_html_dom tries to parse and return its content. I want to avoid this happening by skipping all such links. The problem is that the list is non-exhaustive and I want the code to skip all such links. How am I supposed to do that??

Comment: .htm, .html, .php and many many more are file extensions you will encounter that you will want to scrape, so I don't think blocking all files with extensions is a good idea.

Comment: You are right. But the function should have some exceptions as you have mentioned them.

Comment: Yes, but, just like you cannot make an exhaustive list of extensions to skip, you can't make an exhaustive list of extensions to check. I have even seen websites (such as, in fact, my university) that use a custom extension on the end of all their URLs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tring to filter urls by guessing what's behind it will always fail in a number of cases. Assuming you are using curl to download, you should check if the response document-type header is among the acceptable ones:

```
<?php

require "simple_html_dom.php";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //default is to output it

$urls = array(
  "google.com", 
  "https://www.google.com/logos/2012/newyearsday-2012-hp.jpg", 
  "http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf",
);
$acceptable_types = array("text/html", "application/xhtml+xml");

foreach ($urls as $url) {
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  $contents = curl_exec($curl);

  //we need to handle content-types like "text/html; charset=utf-8"
  list($response_type) = explode(";", curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE));

  if (in_array($response_type, $acceptable_types)) {
    echo "accepting {$url}\n";
    // create a simple_html_dom object from string
    $obj = str_get_html($contents);
  } else {
    echo "rejecting {$url} ({$response_type})\n";
  }
}
```

running the above results in:

```
accepting google.com
rejecting https://www.google.com/logos/2012/newyearsday-2012-hp.jpg (image/jpeg)
rejecting http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf (application/pdf)
```

Comment: Yeah, this way the acceptable headers might be of short listed too. +1

Comment: I am not using curl for the task. I am using Simple_html_dom for the job. Please update your answer to accommodate this.

Comment: @Spoilt, i think you should use curl for scraping. It is much more performance effiecient

Comment: After writing the whole code using simple html dom, it would be impossible to shift to curl right now.

Comment: you might want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566028/extract-doctype-with-simple-html-dom

Answer (score 0):

Update the last regex to something like this:

```
!preg_match('/\.(pdf)|(doc)|(jpg)|(rtf)$/i', $url) )
```

Will filter out the jpgs and rtf documents.

You have to add the extensions to the regex above to omit them.

**Update**

I don’t think its possible to block all sort of extensions and I personally do not recommend it for scraping usage also. You will have to skip some extensions to keep crawling. Why dont you change you regex filter to the ones you would like to accept like:

```
preg_match('/\.(html)|(html)|(php)|(aspx)$/i', $url) )
```

Comment: Well that was obvious and the questions is asking alternatives. I knew I could do this but I don't want it like this. Since file formats on www are non-exhaustive and I want to avoid all of them. The question was how do I do that??

Comment: @Spoilt, I do not understand what you mean by `file formats on www` and what are `non-exhaustive` also?

Comment: I guess i came to answer, but going to learn something instead :)

Comment: Well consider this:
stanford.edu/UG.pdf
stanford.edu/UG.doc

All these links point to some documents.

And by non-exhaustive, I mean that the extension can be anything such as .zip, .7z, .jpg, .bmp, ................

Comment: On your update:

Don't you think this will cause all such links to escape:
Example: stanford.edu has no such extension, yet it is a valid link to be scraped.